# Accessing GCP Memorystore from Google Cloud Platform Cloud Shell

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I recently created a redis instance in Google Cloud Platform Memorystore and was trying to connect to it using Cloud Shell.

```
telnet 10.0.0.3 6379
Trying 10.0.0.3...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

But always I'm getting a connection timeout issue. As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance) it states the compute instances which are in the same project should be able to connect to the instance. Did anyone also encounter the same issue ? and are there any resolutions for testing it locally ?

Comment: Is the Compute VM you are trying to connect from in the same Region and Network as the Redis Instance? Refer to https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/creating-managing-instances#viewing_instance_information to find this information for your Redis Instance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cloud Shell is very limited. The port that you are trying to connect to is not allowed for [`outgoing connections`](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#outgoing_connections). The documentation you shared is referring to a GCE (Google Compute Engine) VM instance, yes Cloud Shell provides a temporary instance but it is very limited. At the moment you can only access it from Compute Engine VM instances, Kubernetes Engine clusters, and App Engine (flexible & standard) as well as Cloud-Functions, you will need to [create a GCE VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#publicimage) and follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance) that you mentioned.